# viewDidAppear is delayed by 0.5 sec

Tags: ios, swift

Greetings StackOverflow!

I'm really new to Swift development, so don't go all crazy on me please :3

I've created a login page for my mobile app (Firebase Email + Password)

I've implemented an "auto login" function - so when a user logs in for the first time, the user stays logged after closing the app & opening it.

The problem is that every time a user opens the app, there is a slight delay between `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear` -> resulting in that every time the app opens, you can see the login screen for about 0.4 sec until it automatically sings the user in.

Once the user logs in the user are segued (no animation) to my `UITabBarController`.

I've provided the code for my `LoginViewController`.

LoginViewController is my first Controller the app loads in.

Best regards

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var loginEmail: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var loginPassword: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var loginBorder: UIButton!

    let userDefault = UserDefaults.standard

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if userDefault.bool(forKey: "usersignedin") {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "login", sender: self)        
        }

        //Border color button//
        loginBorder.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        //Border color button//

        //Hide Keyboard Use
        self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
        //Hide Keyboard Use

        //start padding function for login
        addPaddingAndBorder(to: loginEmail)
        addPaddingAndBorder(to: loginPassword)
        //start padding function for login
    }

    @IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: loginEmail.text!, password: loginPassword.text!) { (user, error) in
            if user != nil {
                self.userDefault.set(true, forKey: "usersignedin")
                self.userDefault.synchronize()
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "login", sender: self)
            } else {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Invalid Email or Password", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
                let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
                alert.addAction(okButton)
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)              
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

We're doing something similar to this in my current project, but we decide which controller to show first in the `AppDelegate`.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    var storyboard: UIStoryboard!
    if isLoggedIn {
        storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "main", bundle: nil)            
    }
    else {
        storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "login", bundle: nil)
    }

    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()!
    viewController.loadViewIfNeeded()
    window.rootViewController = viewController
}
```

This has the advantage that when the app loads it immediately take you to the correct `ViewController` without showing the wrong one briefly first.

Answer (score 1):

Move the call to `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` to `viewWillAppear(_:)` instead of `viewDidAppear(_:)` in case `usersignedin = true`.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if userDefault.bool(forKey: "usersignedin") {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "login", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Also, the response of `signIn` method is not received on the `main thread`. Since you're not updating the `UI` on the `main thread`, that's why it is resulting in the delay.

Embed the `UI` part in `closure` of `signIn` method in **`DispatchQueue.main.async`**

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: loginEmail.text!, password: loginPassword.text!) { (user, error) in
    if user != nil {
        self.userDefault.set(true, forKey: "usersignedin")
        self.userDefault.synchronize()
        DispatchQueue.main.async { //here..........
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "login", sender: self)
        }
    }
    else {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Invalid Email or Password", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(okButton)
        DispatchQueue.main.async { //here..........
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP should do this as well, but not what he was asking about.

Comment: @Maximilian I don't see OP anywhere doing what I suggested.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct system behavior. `ViewDidLoad` will always be called much sooner than `ViewDidAppear`. IF you want to change the base view controller based on `userDefault.bool(forKey: "usersignedin")`, add that logic to where you set the main view controller and swap them if already signed in.

Comment: Hello! thank you for your answer!   my main view controller is LoginViewController tho. Do you mean that i have to move userDefault.bool(forKey: "usersignedin") in to the UITabBarController?

Comment: You can move it into the AppDelegate where you set the `rootViewController` on your window, and then decide which controller should appear first. I saw another answer mentioning to present your tab bar always and then present log in on top if needed, but I don't like that approach since it means one of the tab bar controllers has to know about presenting log in.

Answer (score 1):

Change the order of view controllers. Always load your `UITabBarController` first (as initial controller). Then in your `UITabBarController` `viewDidLoad`, check if the user is logged-in or not. If not, then show the login screen. This way your `UITabBarController` is always loaded first and then based on auto-logn condition, your login screen is displayed. So when the user is auto looged-in then your delay issue will not come.

I have used this concept in all of my apps and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

`viewDidAppear(_:)` happens right after the view appears. I suggest moving your code from `viewDidAppear(_:)` to `viewWillAppear(_:)`.

you can also add your login code in the `viewDidLoad()` because this method is called even before `viewWillAppear(_:)`.

in your case your code will be:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if userDefault.bool(forKey: "usersignedin") {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "login", sender: self)
    }
}
```

---

#### More info:

when a view is loading, there are different methods which get called in a specific order:

1. `viewDidLoad()` (once and only when the object is being created.)
2. `viewWillAppear(_:)`
3. [View appears on the screen]
4. `viewDidAppear(_:)`

when you push another view controller over this one, this view controller won't be removed from the view controllers' stack. the important thing is when you come back to this view controller, this time `viewDidLoad()` won't get called. so only these methods get called again in this order:

1. `viewWillAppear(_:)`
2. [View appears on the screen]
3. `viewDidAppear(_:)`

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to decide in AppDelegate which controller to load based on Login Status

```
        let navigationController = UINavigationController()
        navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Token") != nil{
            let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController")
            navigationController.viewControllers = [initialViewController]
        } else{
            let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController")
            navigationController.viewControllers = [initialViewController]
        }

        navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black
        navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
        navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
        self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```